# Bulk Rename Powershell Script from CSV File not recognizing Values in CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, rename, bulk

I have this code that uses a csv file of old and new names for bulk renaming machines on my domain but my code doesn't recognize the values in my csv file. Any idea how to fix?

```
csvfile = "C:\temp\rename.csv"

if (Test-Path $csvfile) {
    Import-Csv $csvfile | ForEach-Object {
        $oldName = $_.OldName
        $newName = $_.NewName

        if ($oldName -and $newName) {
            Write-Host "Renaming computer from: $oldName to: $newName"
            Rename-Computer -ComputerName $oldName -NewName $newName -DomainCredential   niklas.pusey\username -Force -Restart
        } else {
            Write-Host "Error: CSV file contains empty values"
        }
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "Error: CSV file not found"
}
```

I have tried net cmdlet, but to no avail

CSV File looks as follows:

```
OldName,NewName
ComputerName,NewComputerName
```

I have modified spaces between the commas but that doesn't work. ComputerName is my computer name for testing so it should recognize it.

Comment: Show a sanitized sample of your file, otherwise, any feedback would be just a guess. If you don't have such headers, it will not work until you add them to the file or instantiate them on the load of the file.

Comment: I have added my revisions

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your update.

AS a rule, it is always best to write/run one line of code at a time to ensure you are getting what you'd expect before writing more. It makes debugging far easier.

Well, it does for me.

So, a Q&D (quick and dirty) procedural step-thru of your use case, could be something like this:

```
'OldName       NewName         
-------       -------         
ComputerName  NewComputerName 
ComputerName0                 
ComputerName1 NewComputerName1
              NewComputerName2' | 
Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\rename.csv' -Append

Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\rename.csv'
# Results
<#
OldName,NewName
ComputerName,NewComputerName
ComputerName0,
ComputerName1,NewComputerName1
,NewComputerName2
#>

Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\rename.csv'
# Results
<#
OldName       NewName         
-------       -------         
ComputerName  NewComputerName 
ComputerName0                 
ComputerName1 NewComputerName1
              NewComputerName2
#>

$csvfile = "D:\temp\rename.csv"

Try{Test-Path -Path $csvfile -ErrorAction Stop}
Catch {$Error[0].Exception}
# Results
<#
True
#>

Clear-Host
Try 
{
    Test-Path -Path $csvfile -ErrorAction Stop | 
    Out-Null

    Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\rename.csv' | 
    ForEach-Object {
            If (($PSItem.OldName -eq '') -or ($PSItem.NewName -eq ''))
            {Write-Warning -Message 'One of the value is empty and thus the record cannot be processed'}
            Else {"Renaming computer from $($PSItem.OldName) to $($PSItem.NewName)"}
        }
}
Catch {$Error[0].Exception}
# Results
<#
Renaming computer from ComputerName to NewComputerName
WARNING: One of the value is empty and thus the record cannot be processed
Renaming computer from ComputerName1 to NewComputerName1
WARNING: One of the value is empty and thus the record cannot be processed
#>
```